# Passing ggplot2 function as input in R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I want the user to choose what kind of ggplot graph to display as (geom_plot(), geom_boxplot(), etc.) but I don't know how to pass the "function" and not the string of the function.

One of my inputs look like this:

```
selectInput("graph_type", "Select graph type", 
        c("geom_point()", "geom_boxplot()"), selected = NULL, multiple = FALSE,
        selectize = TRUE, width = NULL, size = NULL)
```

And the output looks like this:

```
  output$p1 = renderPlot({
    ggplot(raw, aes(x=raw[,input$x1], y=raw[,input$y1])) +input$graph_type
```

And the error I get looks like this:

> Error: Don't know how to add input$graph_type to a plot

Can someone help me out? Thanks!

P.S. assume everything else in the code works. Can provide the entire script if needed.

Comment: I assume that `input$graph_type` is being passed as a character so `"geom_point()"`. Since this is the case, `ggplot` does not know how to add it. I would try `as.name(input$graph_type)`

Comment: @WestleyDang if my solution solved your problem you can accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `get` to return value by name of an object.

```
ggplot(raw, aes(x=raw[,input$x1], y=raw[,input$y1])) + 
    get(input$graph_type)()
```

Comment: Might work if you firs stripped the parens. Take a look at this little test: `get( "mean()" ) ###
Error in get("mean()") : object 'mean()' not found`

Comment: You seem to have trouble reading for meaning. The value frorm `selectInput` is what I put inside my `get`. Your `get` argument is not going to be what is returned.

Comment: This worked! I guess it was because I had to exclude the '()' from the input itself? Can someone explain why that is?

Comment: Because `mean()` is NOT a function. It is a "call". They are not the same things. The `name` of the function is `mean`.